# OpenVino and PyInstaller on Raspberry PI 3B+

Tags: python, pyinstaller, raspberry-pi3, raspbian, openvino

I tried to build a standalone executable with PyInstaller for Python 3.5 using OpenVino 2020.4.287.

PyInstaller assembled a file successfully but I received the next error after launch:

```
ImportError: No module named 'openvino'
```

I tried to include /opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/armv7l/plugins.xml in data while building executable but it didn't help.

So the question is how to build a standalone executable in Raspbian with PyInstaller with OpenVino import?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, the issue was resolved.

**Initial conditions:**

Raspbian Stretch with Python 3.5.

**Considerations:**

The last OpenVino supporting Python 3.5 is 2020.4.

So, let’s start. We will create a test.py file with the next lines:

```
import numpy as np
import openvino.inference_engine.constants
from openvino.inference_engine import IENetwork, IECore
print("start")
e = IECore()
print("end")
```

Now let's install OpenVino, Pyinstaller, create an executable, and run it:

```
sudo pip3 install pyinstaller
sudo mkdir -p /opt/intel/openvino
wget https://storage.openvinotoolkit.org/repositories/openvino/packages/2020.4/l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.4.287.tgz
sudo tar -xf l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.4.287.tgz --strip 1 -C /opt/intel/openvino
rm l_openvino_toolkit_runtime_raspbian_p_2020.4.287.tgz
sudo apt install cmake
source /opt/intel/openvino/bin/setupvars.sh
sh /opt/intel/openvino/install_dependencies/install_NCS_udev_rules.sh
pyinstaller --onefile --clean --add-data="/opt/intel/openvino/deployment_tools/inference_engine/lib/armv7l/plugins.xml:." test.py
dist/test
```

"start" and "end" messages should be shown.

The most important when you are using OpenVino 2020.4 is the next line:

```
import openvino.inference_engine.constants
```

In previous versions of OpenVino everything will work normally without this line. But in my specific case I’ve got the next error on OpenVino versions earlier 2020.4:
openvino.inference_engine.ie_api.IECore' object has no attribute 'read_network
That’s why I specified import for **openvino.inference_engine.constants**. Without this nothing works in OpenVino 2020.4.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The biggest possibility is you didn't run the setupvars before that implementation.
Please note that you need to ensure the setupvars had been run and initialized(you should see the init message) in each cmd or terminal before proceeding to any further inferencing/etc.

This setupvars would keep the required packages together. Hence, if you didn't run it, the problem like what you are facing would persist.